# Training TensorFlow Object Detection algorithm - Training step loss unusually low for first steps

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss

I am using Anaconda 3 to train a TensorFlow Object Detection API algorithm (EfficientDet D1, as found on the [TensorFlow 2 Detection Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md)). I have labeled my images with bounding boxes, partitioned the labeled image dataset into 90% training, 10% test images. The "object" to be detected is a family member (strictly for experimental reasons, not to be used for any "tracking" applications), of whom I have amassed 760 images I was successfully able to label. All images were resized to dimensions of 640 x 640 pixels. Training is being done using TensorFlow 2.4.0 on a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 1060 with approximately 7 GB of GPU memory.

The `.config` file that I used to train was as follows:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 640
        max_dimension: 640
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: "ssd_efficientnet-b1_bifpn_keras"
      conv_hyperparams {
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            mean: 0.0
            stddev: 0.029999999329447746
          }
        }
        activation: SWISH
        batch_norm {
          decay: 0.9900000095367432
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
        }
        force_use_bias: true
      }
      bifpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        num_iterations: 4
        num_filters: 88
      }
    }
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 1.0
        x_scale: 1.0
        height_scale: 1.0
        width_scale: 1.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        conv_hyperparams {
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 3.9999998989515007e-05
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              mean: 0.0
              stddev: 0.009999999776482582
            }
          }
          activation: SWISH
          batch_norm {
            decay: 0.9900000095367432
            scale: true
            epsilon: 0.0010000000474974513
          }
          force_use_bias: true
        }
        depth: 88
        num_layers_before_predictor: 3
        kernel_size: 3
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.599999904632568
        use_depthwise: true
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        scales_per_octave: 3
      }
    }
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.5
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    loss {
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          gamma: 1.5
          alpha: 0.25
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
    add_background_class: false
  }
}
train_config {
  batch_size: 1
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_scale_crop_and_pad_to_square {
      output_size: 640
      scale_min: 0.10000000149011612
      scale_max: 2.0
    }
  }
  sync_replicas: true
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer {
      learning_rate {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: 0.07999999821186066
          total_steps: 300000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.0010000000474974513
          warmup_steps: 2500
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.8999999761581421
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "pre-trained-models/efficientdet_d1_coco17_tpu-32/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  num_steps: 300000
  startup_delay_steps: 0.0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  use_bfloat16: false
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
}
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/train.record"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "annotations/test.record"
  }
}
```

The command to start training was:

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_efficientdet_d1 --pipeline_config_path=models/my_efficientdet_d1/pipeline.config --logtostderr --num_train_steps=500000
```

Compared to my previous experiences with training SSD algorithms (which have a higher loss error early on), the early steps of this algorithm had very low losses. Even though I have just begun training, I wonder if this is at all unusual for EfficientDet algorithms:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Step 100 per-step time 0.329s loss=0.547
I0203 10:14:08.874024 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 100 per-step time 0.329s loss=0.547
INFO:tensorflow:Step 200 per-step time 0.280s loss=1.284
I0203 10:14:38.400573 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 200 per-step time 0.280s loss=1.284
INFO:tensorflow:Step 300 per-step time 0.281s loss=1.276
I0203 10:15:07.964723 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 300 per-step time 0.281s loss=1.276
INFO:tensorflow:Step 400 per-step time 0.288s loss=1.135
I0203 10:15:36.975951 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 400 per-step time 0.288s loss=1.135
INFO:tensorflow:Step 500 per-step time 0.312s loss=1.017
I0203 10:16:06.577988 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 500 per-step time 0.312s loss=1.017
INFO:tensorflow:Step 600 per-step time 0.356s loss=1.028
I0203 10:16:37.417855 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 600 per-step time 0.356s loss=1.028
INFO:tensorflow:Step 700 per-step time 0.292s loss=0.969
I0203 10:17:07.432171 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 700 per-step time 0.292s loss=0.969
INFO:tensorflow:Step 800 per-step time 0.328s loss=0.940
I0203 10:17:37.700920 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 800 per-step time 0.328s loss=0.940
INFO:tensorflow:Step 900 per-step time 0.292s loss=0.966
I0203 10:18:07.889194 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 900 per-step time 0.292s loss=0.966
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1000 per-step time 0.286s loss=1.092
I0203 10:18:37.892164 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1000 per-step time 0.286s loss=1.092
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1100 per-step time 0.317s loss=2.630
I0203 10:19:09.544636 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1100 per-step time 0.317s loss=2.630
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1200 per-step time 0.355s loss=1.059
I0203 10:19:40.011054 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1200 per-step time 0.355s loss=1.059
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1300 per-step time 0.301s loss=0.908
I0203 10:20:10.033108 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1300 per-step time 0.301s loss=0.908
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1400 per-step time 0.295s loss=0.927
I0203 10:20:41.024312 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1400 per-step time 0.295s loss=0.927
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1500 per-step time 0.285s loss=1.249
I0203 10:22:56.104043 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1500 per-step time 0.285s loss=1.249
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1600 per-step time 0.324s loss=1.121
I0203 10:23:25.757481 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1600 per-step time 0.324s loss=1.121
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1700 per-step time 0.303s loss=1.209
I0203 10:23:56.077697 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1700 per-step time 0.303s loss=1.209
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1800 per-step time 0.302s loss=0.885
I0203 10:24:26.653827 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1800 per-step time 0.302s loss=0.885
INFO:tensorflow:Step 1900 per-step time 0.319s loss=1.141
I0203 10:24:57.840079 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 1900 per-step time 0.319s loss=1.141
INFO:tensorflow:Step 2000 per-step time 0.298s loss=1.453
I0203 10:25:29.491561 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 2000 per-step time 0.298s loss=1.453
INFO:tensorflow:Step 2100 per-step time 0.296s loss=nan
I0203 10:26:02.341997 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 2100 per-step time 0.296s loss=nan
INFO:tensorflow:Step 2200 per-step time 0.304s loss=nan
I0203 10:26:32.433220 13012 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 2200 per-step time 0.304s loss=nan
```

Granted that I am going to let this run for much longer, **are these low loss rates at all a concern so early on in the training?**

Comment: Yes, this loss is weird. I would suggest inspecting your dataset, it could be a mismatch of bounding boxes coordinates or wrong labels. Also, re-check your code for generating the tfrecord for the same reasons.

Comment: @EmanuelHuber It seems as if I was generating ```.record``` files instead of ```.tfrecord``` files. Could that be an issue? I wonder if I could simply correct it by changing the name of the files to .tfrecord?

Comment: The filename should not be an issue, Tensorflow knows how to read it.